# Solving Path Sum II in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, binary-tree

I'm a beginner in Scala and I am trying to solve the [Path Sum II](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-ii/) on leetcode with Scala which states: Given a binary tree and a sum, find all root-to-leaf paths where each path's sum equals the given sum.

Note: A leaf is a node with no children.

I came up with this solution which so far has worked for trees with positive integers only but fails on trees including negative integers and after hours of trying, I've decided to seek your help.

```
/**
* Definition for a binary tree node.
* class TreeNode(var _value: Int) {
*   var value: Int = _value
*   var left: TreeNode = null
*   var right: TreeNode = null
* }
*/
object Solution {
 def pathSum(root: TreeNode, sum: Int): List[List[Int]] = {
   if (root == null) List()
   else if(root.value == sum && (root.right == null && root.left == null)) List(List(root.value))
   else
     pathSumhelper2(pathSumhelper(root.left, sum, root.value, root.value::Nil, Nil) :::
       pathSumhelper(root.right, sum, root.value, root.value::Nil, Nil))
 }

 def pathSumhelper2(l1: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = l1 match {
   case Nil => l1
   case x :: y => x.reverse :: pathSumhelper2(y)
 }


 def pathSumhelper(root: TreeNode, sum: Int, accumSum: Int, currentList: List[Int], result: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = {

   if (root==null) result
   else if (accumSum+root.value==sum) (root.right,root.left) match {
   case(null,null) => root.value :: currentList match { case x => x :: result}
       case(_,_) => result
   }
 else {
     root.value :: currentList match {
       case x => (pathSumhelper(root.left, sum, root.value + accumSum, x, result) :::
         pathSumhelper(root.right, sum, root.value + accumSum, x, result)).distinct
     }
   }
 }  
}
```

I understand with negative numbers it is possible to get the sum and not be at a root node however I am not sure how to add this check, probably due to my implementation. Would appreciate if anyone could enlighten me on how to add this constraint or any comments on my approach.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a couple of years since I solved this one. Reviewing the old code it looks like the idea is to subtract `value` from `sum` with each recursion so that when we reach a leaf node we just test for `sum == value`.

```
def pathSum(root:TreeNode, sum:Int, path:List[Int]=List()):List[List[Int]] = {
  if (root == null) List()
  else if (root.left == null && root.right == null)
    if (sum == root.value) List((root.value :: path).reverse)
    else List[List[Int]]()
  else
    Option(root.left).fold(List[List[Int]]()) {tn =>
      pathSum(tn, sum-root.value, root.value::path)} :::
      Option(root.right).fold(List[List[Int]]()) {tn =>
        pathSum(tn, sum-root.value, root.value::path)}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my passed solution:

```
def pathSum(root: TreeNode, sum: Int): List[List[Int]] ={
    if(root == null) Nil
    else if(root.right == null && root.left == null) if(sum == root.value) List(List(sum)) else Nil
    else (pathSum(root.left, sum-root.value) ++ pathSum(root.right, sum-root.value)).map(root.value::_)
}
```

> Runtime: 564 ms, faster than 92.86% of Scala online submissions for
>   Path Sum II. Memory Usage: 53.9 MB, less than 100.00% of Scala online
>   submissions for Path Sum II.